# SwiftUI: Empty Detail View After Second NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

there is an interesting bug after the iOS 15 release. It was working well till iOS 15 but something went wrong after it.

I have a drawer menu, when users click on a category, I trigger hidden NavigationLink to go to the category page. There is no problem till here. It's occurring when users click on the news to go to the detail. It's showing only a blank page. When I add NavigationLink scope to top-level on CategoryView it's working fine but this time there are two navigations on the page on the same page.

CategoryView

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack{ // When I change this with NavigationLink it's working well
            if viewModel.news.count > 0 {
                List{
                    ForEach(Array(self.viewModel.news.enumerated()), id: \.1) { index, element in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: LazyView(HaberDetay(id: .constant(element.id), type: .constant(element.rights ?? ""))),
                            label: {
                                UI codes....
                            })
                            .onAppear {
                                self.viewModel.loadMoreArticles(currentItem: element, id: self.id)
                            }
                    }
                }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            }else{
                Group{
                    if viewModel.error == true{
                        ConnectionError()
                    }else{
                        LoadingView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            self.viewModel.loadMoreArticles(id: self.id)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(title), displayMode: .inline)
    }
```

ContentView

```
@ViewBuilder
func buildView() ->  some View {
    switch self.menuVM.option {
    case "new":
        HaberDetay(id: self.$selectedNew, type: self.$selectedNewType)
    case "category":
        CategoryView(id: self.$menuVM.selectedCatID, title: self.$menuVM.selectedCatTitle, icon: self.$menuVM.selectedCatIcon)
    case "page":
        PageView(title: $menuVM.pageTitle, content: $menuVM.pageContent, icon: .constant(""))
    case "table":
        PuanDurumu()
    default:
        EmptyView()
    }
}
    
    var body: some View {
        SideMenu(content: AnyView(
            NavigationView{
                ZStack{
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: LazyView(self.buildView()), isActive: $menuVM.showDetail) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }.hidden()

                   UI Codes...
                    
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Image("orta").resizable().foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "DarkColor")!))
                                        .frame(width: 34, height: 34), trailing: Button(action: {
                    withAnimation{
                        self.isDrawerOpen.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "text.alignright").renderingMode(.template).foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "DarkColor")!))
                })
            }.phoneOnlyStackNavigationView()
                .onAppear(){
                    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
                    navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
                    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
                    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
                    if self.menuVM.menu.count == 0 {
                        self.menuVM.fetchMenu()
                    }
                    self.sliderVM.fetchSliderNews()
                    self.otherVM.selected = 0
                }), isPresented: $isDrawerOpen)
    }
```

phoneOnlyStackNavigationView Extension:

```
extension View{
    func phoneOnlyStackNavigationView() ->some View{
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone{
            return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle()))
        }else{
            return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()))
        }
    }
}
```

I researched it a lot but it seems no one faced with this issue, as I said before it occurred automatically after iOS 15 :(

Comment: I think you should start your new research with [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) there is a lot in your code that can make this not work.[Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) might help clear stuff up too. `constant` is a dead end, it should be used outside of previews, `AnyView` causes a lot to get lost, its use should be the exception.

Comment: @loremipsum It was my first SwiftUI project and I still maintain it and I don't have any free time to write this app from zero. I know it's not so good but at least it was working well till to iOS 15 release.

Comment: You haven't provided a  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) there is no way to help you troubleshoot. iOS 15 fixed a lot of bugs that allowed this kind of stuff to appear that it was working fine.

Comment: @loremipsum thanks bro you helped me a lot thanks to making my motivation down lol It wasn't needed, I just wanted to solve this issue :(

Comment: @loremipsum was not trying to kill your motivation, but in order to help you with this bug in your app, we need enough code to be able to run a facsimile to see what the problem is. Nothing is jumping out to us from what is provided, so we need to be able to build and run, and that is a minimal reproducible example. So much has changed in SwiftUI from when you wrote this app, as well as how we, as developers, approach apps with SwiftUI. Into, would recommend Demystify Swift, as it explains why these practices impact the results and performance of SwiftUI apps.

Comment: yeah I see, but you hurt me a bit at first saying it would be better if you started from the beginning. Anyway thanks for the Demystify Swift recommendation, I knew these things but it was good for me to consolidate my knowledge. I solved this issue, I just removed @Binding properties and made them standart variable, that's it lol

Comment: When did I say for you to start at the beginning? Lol. I just piggybacked on your last line where you said you researched. Don’t be demotivated, take it one step at a time. It will come together quicker than you think. BTW I meant constant should NOT be used outside of previews.